# OWIN asynchronous startup (using Hangfire)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, hangfire

I am using Hangfire with SQL Storage on a remote SQL server and running it alongside my existing MVC site.  My startup class is very simple:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) 
{
        app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("MY_CONNECTION_STRING");
            config.UseServer();
        });
}
```

The problem is that any delay in connecting to the remote server delays my MVC site from spinning up.  Is there a way to start OWIN asynchronously so that the project is able to respond to requests regardless of what happens during the OWIN startup, including fatal errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hangfire initialization logic is performed in a dedicated thread to decrease the start-up time of your application. So, `UseServer` method creates a new thread only, without any additional logic.

`UseSqlServerStorage` method connects to your database to check your current schema to run automatic migrations if necessary (one simple query to the `Hangfire.Schema` table). This is the default behavior, however you are able to [disable it](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#installing-objects):

```
var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = false
};

var storage = new SqlServerStorage("<name or connection string>", options);
```

After performing this step, Hangfire will not connect to your database at startup (and no other class will do it). *But keep an eye on release notes*, they will contain information about database storage changes.